# getting the last index, better to use len(list)-1 or use own variable?

Tags: python

In my code below, would it be better to use the i = len(scheduled_meetings)-1 or the i=0/i+=1 method? I know the cost of len() is O(1) and it's probably more clear whats going on this way, but it gets calculated for every m in sorted_meetings. i=0 is set once then only incremented if something is appended to the list. Will there even be a difference? Both methods work against my test cases, just wanted to get some feedback on which would be better.

```
import operator

def answer(meetings):
    # sort by earliest end time
    sorted_meetings = sorted(meetings, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    # always select the earilest end time
    scheduled_meetings = [sorted_meetings[0]]
    i = 0 #METHOD B
    for m in sorted_meetings:
        i = len(scheduled_meetings) - 1 #METHOD A
        if m[0] >= scheduled_meetings[i][1] or m[1] <= scheduled_meetings[i][0]:
            scheduled_meetings.append(m)
            i += 1 #METHOD B

    return len(scheduled_meetings)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use neither of these. Use `your_list[-1]` instead. It's less code and doesn't require other variables like `i`.

`-1` means *the first element from the right* which is apparently the last element of the list.

See *Example 3.7* [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html) for more information about negative list indexes.